# MSBuild incorrectly resolves references in custom build target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I had to create a custom MSBuild Target, because I have multiple CS files with naming convention and all files (mostly 1-3 files) have to be compiled into a single assembly. To make it simple, let's make an assumption there is 1 file per DLL. It means there are:

```
files/file1.cs
files/file2.cs
files/file3.cs
```

and in the output there should be File1.dll, File2.dll File3.dll

So I created a custom MSBuild target, which looks like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CSFile Include="file\*.cs" Exclude="" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.dll"/>
    <Reference Include="..\libs\customdll.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CompileFiles" Inputs="@(CSFile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath) (CSFile.Filename).dll" >
    <CSC Sources="%(CSFile.Identity)" TargetType="library" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)%(CSFile.Filename).dll" References="@(Reference)"/>
</Target>
```

And it worked at some point, but now when I want to hook some Nuget packages to it (it's not related to NuGet itself, but it appeared when I tried to change some references paths) and

```
<Reference Include="..\libs\customdll.dll"/>
```

Is changed to

```
<Reference Include="customdll"/>
  <HintPath>..\libs\customdll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

It simply doesn't work. It looks like MSBuild doesn't resolve references correctly and only uses value in "Include" attribute. It doesn't check HintPaths, System paths etc. Moreover, when I try to add `DependsOnTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"` to the `Target` then I see full paths in references when `CSC` is invoked (when `@(Reference)` is changed to `@(ReferencePath)`), but surprisingly some basic references like `System` or `System.Core` etc. seem to be included multiple times and compiler complains that I have to remove duplicates. Even if I remove them from the `<ItemGroup><Reference>..` the error is still the same.

So generally there are 2 kinds of errors. First that basically says `Metadata file`System`could not be found` when I don't use that `ResolveAssemblyReferences` target from common targets in Microsoft.CSharp, which basically means it cannot resolve references and the second error is when I use it and references are resolved correctly, but libs are included somehow multiple times and it still cannot be compiled.

Any idea how to fix that? or maybe how should my MSBuild target look like to achieve a goal which is DLL per some criteria, without full working CSPROJ genrated by VisualStudio.

I've tried MSBuild tools 4.0, 12.0. and various combinations of .NET4.0/.NET4.5 target frameworks.

Comment: Nuget packages expect to be loaded into "standard" C# projects and mangle the project file based on this assumption. Either unmangle after restoring Nuget or extract the nuget packages manually (they're just zip files).

Answer (score 0):

Three idea comes to my mind:

1) try play with "AdditionalLibPaths" and "BaseAddress" parameters from Csc taks.

2) If you says that `@(ReferencePath)` contains duplicates - so removes them. But not from the `Reference` items, but from `ReferencePath`, after running target ResolveAssemblyReferences.
Try the `RemoveDuplicates` task

3) (this will be my approach) forget running csc by your own. Create two separate files (Main.proj and FileBuild.proj) and use standard well-known MSBuld task.
(I write from-the-head, so some types could be found here :P this is just a concept)

Main.proj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CSFile Include="file\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CompileFiles">
  <MSBuild Projects="FileBuild.proj" Properties="CsFile=%(CSFile.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

And the FileBuild.proj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>$(CsFile)</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.dll"/>
    <Reference Include="..\libs\customdll.dll"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(CsFile)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Of course you will have to set additional information in FileBuild (like change AssemblyName to contains only Filename without extension) or if you really need Inputs/Outputs you have to grab Outputs from MSBuild in Main.proj.

Comment: All this because MSDN decided to change the priority of reference paths when looking for external DLL?
I vote rollback.